# Extension chrome.tabs.executeScript executing weirdly with React children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and some JavaScript I am trying to inject into a React page that edits some react nodes. It works when pasted in through the developer console, but not when using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

Here's the script being injected:

```
etInterval(function() {
    let answerKeyZoom = Object.values(document.querySelector('#app > div > div'))[1].children[1]._owner.stateNode.state.question.answers;
    Object.values(document.querySelector('#app > div > div'))[1].children[1]._owner.stateNode.state.question.correctAnswers = answerKeyZoom;
}, 10);
```

And here's the thing executing it:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: `
                        (function(){
                          window.nullbyteCheckedArg1 = ${nullbyteCheckedArg1};
                          window.nullbyteCheckedArg2 = ${nullbyteCheckedArg2};
                          window.nullbyteCheckedArg3 = ${nullbyteCheckedArg3};
                          window.nullbyteCheckedArg4 = ${nullbyteCheckedArg4};
                          window.nullbyteCheckedArg5 = ${nullbyteCheckedArg5};
                
                          window.nullbyteSliderArg1 = ${nullbyteSliderArg1};
                          window.nullbyteSliderArg2 = ${nullbyteSliderArg2};
                          window.nullbyteSliderArg3 = ${nullbyteSliderArg3};
                          window.nullbyteSliderArg4 = ${nullbyteSliderArg4};
                          window.nullbyteSliderArg5 = ${nullbyteSliderArg5};
                
                          ${getscript.responseText}
                        })();
                        `,
    allFrames: true
});
```

The error when run via extension
`caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children') at <anonymous>:15:130 (`

I've tried countless things but nothing seems to work

Tried putting it in an IIFE but still no luck